# load another view on ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view **UserInformation** where I am filling few user related information and posting those information to another View "AnotherView" using ajax post.

Now I want to take these inputs in action method "AnotherView" and load the view "AnotherView" with some datamodel.

When I am doing Ajax Post from view **UserInformation** to action method **"AnotherView"**,It is going to action method **"AnotherView"**,but it is still showing view **UserInformation**

Ajax call from view **UserInformation**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/AnotherView/',
    data: {
        name: $.trim($('#mgr').val()),
        id: $('#id').val(),
        email: $.trim($('#hdnMgrmail').val())
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data,
        textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert('ok');
    }
});


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnotherView(few parametrs that is coming here)
{
      //create model using input params
      return View(with some model);
}
```

Comment: You need to add the partial view returned by your `AnotherView()` method to the DOM in the success callback - e.g. `$(someElement).html(data);`

Comment: Does the data variable in your success function not contain the HTML content of AnotherView? All you should need to do is place this content where you need it.

Comment: I have to load full view not partial

Comment: Then do not use ajax!

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using ajax to post this - do a full postback to AnotherView and have it `return View` instead of `return PartialView`

Comment: can i use  Ajax.BeginForm post in  view UserInformation and keep my action method same as it is?

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm()` is just a wrapper around `$.ajax()` If you want to display a different view, make a normal submit and redirect.

Comment: thanks stephen,got it.if i do full submit ,it doesn't require any change in my above action,is itcorrect?

Comment: @F11. No,but because your use `return View(..);` rather that `return RedirectToAction(...)` the url in you browser will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your target Controller Action is returning an `ActionResult`, then you can expect that it will be returning the rendered HTML (along with any data-binding that occurred).

So the `data` parameter of your success callback will actually contain this contents, so you can simply use a jQuery selector to determine where you want to output it using the `html()` function:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    // data is your HTML content
    $(...).html(data);
}
```

It's worth noting that you may want to consider using the `PartialView()` method if you intend on this returning a small segment of content as opposed to any additional things (like the layout or other related views):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnotherView(...)
{
     return PartialView(...);
}
```

**Update**

Since it was mentioned in the comments that it is preferred to have a complete refresh of the page, if that is the case, then you may consider simply submitting a form that posts to the target action and the submission event will handle navigating (and returning the entire action):

```
<form action='/somecontroller/AnotherView/' method='post'>
    <input id='mgr' name='name' />
    <input id='id' name='id' />
    <input id='hdnMgrmail' name='email' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks rion,let me try it out.just one more query,if i use form action post,i believe i don't have to make any changes in action method.is it correct?

Comment: Correct. You won't need to return a `PartialView()` if you are submitting the form as it will return the entire view after the POST has completed.